# Web Server for existing Java application

Tags: java, webserver

I have an existing Java application running on a linux box that monitors the state of relays and network information. This is a stand-alone device currently.

What I would like to further develop is a web server for the device to remotely monitor, configure, and control the device via an Ethernet connection. To achieve this, I need some way to interface between the web server, which could be configured as enabled/disabled, and the master device, which is always running.

Is there a good way to do this? I have looked at apache w/ tomcat and similar web servers but not sure if this is what I need. The key here is that the web server needs to be able to access the existing java application without interfering with its always running services.

Comment: Perhaps, `MBean` would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

You either develop a webapp, use your Java application's API inside the webapp, and deploy this webapp inside a web container. Or you can do the reverse and embed a web server inside your application (see here for [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) to embed Jetty).

If you want to keep the webapp and the original application in two separate JVMs, you'll need some wey to communicate between both, like sockets, RMI, or even files, but it will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at JMX http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/index.html